# Matlab's trick to increment variable

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, matrix, range

How to increment a variable by a infinite set of numbers, in *Matlab*. I'v a variable which I want to increment till the loop ends by 0.1 every time but through set of range.
I'm currently doing this by:   `K=K*0.1; %K = 2 initially` but I want this same by *Matlab's* trick of ranged values like `[0.1:0.1:9]` where `9` is the loop condination.

**My Code:**

```
K=2;
for ii=1:9
K=K*0.1;
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `for ii=1:9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the **cumprod** command which returns the cumulative product of the elements in a matrix or vector.  For your example, something like:

```
K=cumprod([2 repmat(0.1,1,9)]);  % returns a row vector of 9 elements
```

**repmat** just creates a row vector of nine elements each set to the value **0.1**. The last element in the vector, **K(end)**, will be the product returned by your example. i.e.`K = 2*0.1^9;`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly:

```
for K = 2 * 0.1.^(1:9)
    %// do something with K
end
```

Comment: Perhaps the range should be `0:8`, to include `K = 2`.

Comment: It can possibe without a for loop ?

Comment: @user3593525 That depends on whether the operation you want to do on `K` can be vectorized. For example: `K = 2 * 0.1.^(1:9); y = sqrt(K);`. This is possible because `sqrt` allows vector input